# Do literature interpretations actually reflect what the author had in mind?

Tags: authorial-intent

I read an [article](https://www.huffpost.com/entry/standardized-tests-are-so-bad-i-cant-answer-these_b_586d5517e4b0c3539e80c341) about a writer who was asked about the interpretation of one of his books, and he had a hard time coming up with something that would be aligned with the expectations of the jury. This was an American article about some kind of state-wide standardized tests all children must pass and being French I did not really understand what they were.

This led me to wonder **whether there were studies about how the interpretation of contemporary literature matches the interpretation of the author of the book**.

I was always amazed by how much my French teacher managed to squeeze out of a piece of literature and it sometimes seemed borderline (although these interpretations were probably aligned with the official curriculum)

Comment: Strongly related: [How much weight is given to authors' intentions in literary analysis?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/608/17) and [The author of a literary work disagrees with critics about meaning—who's right?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/2009/17)

Comment: In addition to the related questions pointed out by Rand al'Thor and Mithical, also consider the following: (1) How would we know what the author had in mind if the author died long ago and left no statements about his intentions? (2) What if the author changed their mind? Which "intent" counts? (3) How do you know whether an author gives you an honest answer when you ask what they had in mind?